# ¿Cómo relacionar la tabla de órdenes con la de los productos (en diferentes tablas) en SQL?

Tags: sql, tablas

Tengo una tabla de `ordenes` y otras 3 tablas que son los productos/servicios que guarda la información que está solicitando el cliente (`folletos`, `clasificados`, `desplegados`).

Lo que busco es cómo poder relacionar estas tablas siguiendo la siguiente lógica:
Dentro de una orden del cliente puede tener uno o varios productos diferentes (clasificados, folletos y/o desplegados).

Por ejemplo, la orden 1 tiene el id 3 y 4 de la tabla `folletos` y el 10 de `desplegados`.

No estoy seguro de que así como lo tengo se pueda relacionar directamente la orden con los productos sin una tabla intermedia ya que no le encontraría sentido, probablemente necesite una tabla `items_ordenes` y/o `detalles_items_ordenes` que es lo que he estado tratando de modelar o incluso un campo único que no se repita en ningún producto como `folio`, pero me confundo más al pensar su relación.

Adjunto la imagen del diagrama que estoy haciendo:

[image: BD - ORDENES]

Comment: si, te falta una tabla intermedia

Comment: Yo diría que te faltan dos: productos y productos_orden. La primera para almacenar los atributos comunes a todos tus tipos de producto, el más importante un código único de producto. La segunda es la que establecería qué productos corresponden a una orden concreta (la que tú has indicado como items_orden, pero con mi nombre sugerido queda más claro qué dos tablas relaciona)

Comment: Creo que puedes optimizar tu modelo creando una tabla producto y tipo_producto. En tipo_producto le colocas como descripción si es un folleto, un clasificado o un desplegado. En la tabla producto le colocarías los campos de descripción, peso e imagen. Luego de esto crear una tabla de detalles_orden la cual tendría relacionado un producto por cada detalle de tu orden.

Comment: ¿ *"folio"* de qué?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que puedes optimizar tu modelo creando una tabla producto y tipo_producto. En tipo_producto le colocas como descripción si es un folleto, un clasificado o un desplegado. En la tabla producto le colocarías los campos de descripción, peso e imagen. Luego de esto crear una tabla de detalles_orden la cual tendría relacionado un producto por cada detalle de tu orden.

Considero que para lo que necesitas debes tener algo parecido a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente podría funcionar, me has dado la idea para basarme en ella.

Comment: Acá estamos para ayudarnos. Si mi respuesta te ayudo a solucionar tu problema, puedes marcarla como aceptada :) @Ominous